# How much memory does each apppool use by default in IIS 6.0?

Tags: iis-6

How much memory does Windows or IIS 6.0 allocate by default for each web site when each site runs in its own AppPool? The effect memory wise when web sites share the same AppPool vs each in a separate one. I am talking about when websites start up, not when web sites start using memory when they run applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanilla Windows server 2003 IIS 6.0 process consumes about 5mb of memory.